# Can I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where the off-diagonal elements of the Hesse Matrix are zero everywhere?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

While toying with the possible solutions of a differential equation, I see that some solutions are possible, if the Hesse Matrix (matrix of 2nd derivatives) of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ has diagonal form, i.e. the off-diagonal elements are zero.

1. I wonder if such an $f$ possible at all apart from trivial solutions where all 2nd derivatives are zero?
2. If yes, are there any obvious features of $f$ to note?

(Ok, these are nearly two questions. Don't know if this is allowed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding 1.:**
Let $g_1,g_2,g_3 \in C^2 (\mathbb R)$ and $f(x):=g_1(x_1) + g_2(x_2) + g_3(x_3)$ then
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} f(x) = 0 \qquad \forall i\neq j$$
**Regarding 2.:**
Consider any planar function, i.e. $f$ as above with $g_i(x_i):= \alpha_i x_i + \beta_i$

Answer (score 1):

How about $\mathrm{f}(x,y,z) = a(x-p)^2+b(y-q)^2+c(z-r)^2$, for arbitrary constants $a,b,c,p,q,r$?

Comment: I see. I think it could be even more general. Should not $f(x,y,z) = g_1(x) + g_2(y) + g_3(z)$ work, because every first derivative is a $g_i'(\phi)$ where $\phi$ is one of the variables and any second derivative involving another variable will be zero.

Comment: The general solution will be a sum of a smooth function of $x$, a smooth function of $y$, and a smooth function of $z$.